# Pass by value-doesn't execute as I want it

Tags: c

I do not understand the concept of pass by value in C. Here is my function:

```
void add(int x){
   x = x+1;
}
```

and when I call the function:

```
int y=3; 

add(y);
```

but when I compile, I still get 3. I've been told it has something to do with pass-by-value but I still do not understand? Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Because as you  have named it. It is pass-by-value. The value is passed, the variable itself is not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/315052

Comment: thanks everyone! This is very clear! So basically, if we want to modify a value in c, we could: 1). not use void for functions  2). use pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Pass by value creates a copy of the argument. It is this copy that is changed in the function

```
void add(int x){
   x = x+1;
}
```

Thus the change you make is made to the copy and not the variable in your `main` scope (that you are expecting to see changed).

If you want to change a variable within a function by passing it as a parameter you cannot pass by value. You could change your function to pass by pointer like this

```
void add(int* x){
   *x = *x + 1;
}
```

and pass the address of an integer to the function like this

```
int y=3;
add(&y);
```

within `main()`

The **pointer** is still passed by value so it is a copy of the pointer that is being acted on, but this doesn't matter as you are not changing the pointer itself, you are changing the value of the variable it points to.

Answer (score 3):

This function:

```
void add(int x) {
    x = x + 1;
}
```

Essentially says this: create a function named `add`, that returns nothing (`void`), and takes a single integer argument `x`.  Then you call the function:

```
y = 3;
add(y);
```

This says "Set the variable named `y` to 3. Now call the `add()` function passing as an argument the *current value* of `y`, namely 3. This is no different from

```
add(3);
```

The argument `x` is entirely local to the function `add()`. It exists only inside the function, and does not affect anything outside it.

So your function dutifully adds 1 to the number you gave it, and then throws it away. Just like you told it to.

C has no "pass by reference" like other languages, where you can tell a function to act on a variable itself rather than its current value. It does, however, have *pointers*, which can accomplish similar things.

Answer (score 3):

All function arguments in C are passed by value.  That means that the parameter (in this case, `x` defined in `add`) is initialized to a *copy* of the value of the argument (in this case, `y`, which has the value `3`).

Since `x` is a local variable, executing

```
x = x + 1;
```

changes the value of `x`, but that change has no effect after the function returns and `x` no longer exists.

Note that the argument doesn't have to be the name of a variable. You can legally call your function like this:

```
add(42);
```

`x` is initialized to `42` -- but `x = x + 1` certainly isn't going to change the value of `42`.

If you want to modify the value, you can have the function *return* the new value:

```
int add(int x) {    
    return x + 1;
}
```

The caller can do anything it likes with the result, including assigning it back to the variable:

```
int y = 3;
y = add(y);
```

**Or** you can pass the *address* of the object you want to modify:

```
int add(int *x) {
    *x = *x + 1;
}
```

and then the caller can do this:

```
int y = 3;
add(&y);
```

This is still pass-by-value, but the value being passed is a pointer value, the address of `x`. It's how we can *emulate* pass-by-reference in C.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve above by using the code :

int add(int x)
{ x=x+1;
return x;}
then use 
a new variable like
k= add(y);
and then print k.